# Converting SVG's font-size to an NSFont size

Tags: cocoa, svg, webkit, font-size, nsfont

Bit of an obscure one this - I'm hoping that someone out there knows a fair bit about the internals of Webkit.

The SVG specification describes font-size thus: "This property refers to the size of the font from baseline to baseline when multiple lines of text are set solid in a multiline layout environment. For SVG, if a  is provided without a unit identifier (e.g., an unqualified number such as 128), the SVG user agent processes the  as a height value in the current user coordinate system."

What I'd like to know is how Webkit maps this value to an actual NSFont pointSize in OS X.

Simply passing in this value to NSFont as the size doesn't seem to be sufficient, even accounting for some scaling to/from user coordinates and pts. I'm guessing that this is because NSFont's pointSize does not correspond to the baseline-to-baseline measurement that SVG apparently uses. So the question is - how to get there from here?

Comment: Before anyone else says it, I should probably say that yes, I can look at the source of WebKit. In fact, I have started to look at it, but there's a lot of code there, and I've not yet found the relevant bit :)

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS standard a pixel ("px") is defined as 1/96 of an inch.  A point is 1/72 of an inch.

Assuming the SVG is being rendered at 1:1 (ie no scaling is in affect), "128" is the same as "128px".

So given the ratio of px:pt is 4:3, "128" should correspond to 96pt.

Does this answer your question?